# Problems updating manytomany reference in Symfony with Sonata and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm having some problems updating a reference from one collection to another in Symfony2 with mongoDB using Sonata Admin Bundle.

I have created this reference between the users and the communities they can admin.

This one is in the Community class

```
class Community
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
     *      targetDocument="User",
     *      inversedBy="communitiesAdmin",
     *  )
     */
    protected $usersAdministrator;
```

And this one in the User

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
     *      targetDocument="Community",
     *      mappedBy="usersAdministrator",
     * )
     */
    protected $communitiesAdmin;
```

and this is the way I show the field in Sonata

```
    $formMapper
        ->with('Community Administrators')
            ->add('usersAdministrator', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true))
        ->end()
```

When i track the collection in MongoHub the reference is being created but I cannot update it because the data previously inserted is not being shown when I edit the community.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it with :

```
public function addVideo($video)
{
    $this->videos[] = $video;
    $video->addArtist($this); << This makes doctrine handle the bi direction
}
```

In Admin :

```
        ->add('videos', 'sonata_type_model', array(
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
```

by_reference = FALSE is really important !